# Bootstrap sticky nav and grid issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav, sticky

am using Bootstrap for overall site, but have had to put main content in a 12 column grid with % margins to create an 'edge'. Have got a secondary sticky nav working for in page linking (not with affix) but issue is that on wider screen sizes, once the nav fixes it removes itself from the 12 columns (z-index 9999) and floats left - any idea how to keep centred and 'back on grid' would be much appreciated..!

HTML

```
            <div id="strip" class="strip"> 
                <div id="navstrip"> 
                <ul class="navstrip navbar-nav2">  
                    <li><a href="#content1">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#content2">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#content3">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#content4">Link 4</a></li> 
                </ul> 
                </div> <!-- /navstrip -->
            </div> 

        </div>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

CSS

```
body 
{
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background: #bfbfbf;
}

.col-lg-12
{
    width: 84%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
}

#navstripbase
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 45px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#strip 
{
    top: 56px;
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#navstrip 
{
    background-color: #626767;
    text-align: center;
}

#navstrip ul 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navstrip li 
{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    display: inline;
}

#navstrip ul li a 
{
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.navbar-fixed-top and .navbar-fixed-bottom sets the position of your element to fixed.

you can position fixed elements by setting top, right, bottom, left to something.
the position is relative to its parent. position of parent cannot be static.

you probably have to do somesthing like this:

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="strip" class="strip"> 
      <div id="navstrip"> 
        <ul class="navstrip navbar-nav2">  
          <li><a href="#content1">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#content2">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#content3">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#content4">Link 4</a></li> 
        </ul> 
      </div> <!-- /navstrip -->
    </div> 
  </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

css

```
.strip {
  position: relative;
}

#navstrip {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```